# Типы typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Функция возращает объект с вложенными объектами `wrapper` и `title` . Каким образом можно указать что у ВСЕХ значений в объектах `wrapper` и `title` тип `String`. Просто не вижу смысла для каждого св-ва описывать тип. Может я не прав, подскажите плз.

```js
let style = () => {
  return {
    wrapper: {
      width: '150px',
      border: '1px solid black',
      color: 'red',
    },
    title: {
      color: 'red',
      height: '150px',
      margin: '0 auto'
  }
  }
}
//==========================

interface Style {
  wrapper: {
    width: string;
    border: string;
    color: string;
  },
  title: {
    color: string;
    height: string;
    margin: string;
  }

}
```

Comment: `wrapper: Record<string, string>`, или `wrapper: Record<'width' | 'border' | 'color', string>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
interface Style {
  wrapper: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>
  title: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>
}
```

или

```
interface Style {
  wrapper: { [key: string]: string }
  title: { [key: string]: string }
}
```

или

```
interface Style {
  [key: string]: { [key: string]: string }
}
```

или

```
interface Style {
  [key: string]: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>
}
```

Comment: О, спасибо большое за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете автоматизировать процесс, передав аргументы функции и использовать проверку не разные типы.
Смотреть консоль.

```html
let style = () => {
  return {
    wrapper: {
      width: 150,
      border: '1px solid black',
      color: 'red',
    },
    title: {
      color: 'red',
      height: '150px',
      margin: '0 auto'
  }
  }
}    

const obj = style();

function checkObjType(content) {  
  const answerArr = []
  const arr = Object.values(content); 
  for (el of arr) {  
    console.log(typeof el)
    typeof el === 'string' ? answerArr.push(el) : answerArr.push(`Не  string ${el}`);
  } 
  return answerArr;
}
 
console.log(checkObjType(obj.wrapper));
```

Хотя возможно это не совсем то, что нужно.

Comment: вопрос про typescript, ваш ответ совершенно о другом

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Да, это немножко не совсем то что нужно, но пример полезный, разберу его обязательно.

Comment: Да, извините, не так понял. Ответ дан выше в таком случае, удалить данный вариант или оставить?

Comment: Не удаляйте) Хочу потом разобрать его